# Orchestration tools to be integrated within Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am having a requirement where there is a need to go away with "TASKS" which is currently used as an orchestration for multiple  stored procedures written within Snowflake.

I am evaluating "AIRFLOW" know as a replacement for TASK in this process. As I want to do a POC around it. If anyone can please help provide some reference docs/pointers to do them it would be great.

What is needed ?
--> How Apache Airflow would be connected to Snowflake.
--> How using airflow we can schedule the procedure sequentially, parallelly, etc.
--> Logging/error handling features.
--> Any best practices around governance.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

Reference for your consideration:

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-connect-Apache-Airflow-to-Snowflake-and-schedule-queries-jobs